Matplotlib plots not showing in VSCode in interactive mode
I use matplotlib in interactive mode in VSCode to debug. In the past, I had been able to see plots immediately. I recently updated to VSCode version 1.89.1 and matplotlib version 3.9.0, python 3.10.14 and this no longer works for me. Plots from matplotlib do not show up when I think I should.
I tried the following test code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

plt.ion()

print('plt.isinteractive() =', plt.isinteractive())
plt.plot(123,123,'ro')
plt.show()
print('you should see something...')
time.sleep(10)
_ = input('press enter to continue')


If I choose "Run without debugging" I don't see the plot until after the sleep statement finishes, same if I run in debug mode and step through each line, while I expected the plot to show up after the plt.plot(...) line. If I set plt.show(block=True), it does show the plot in either mode. This all works normally in python in a terminal, either running or in pdb. My backend is tkAgg. This is not in a notebook.
This used to work as expected for me in version VSCode v1.88.1 with matplotlib v3.7.1 in python 3.9.6, i.e. plot would show up after plt.plot(...) line, I suspect the main difference is the VSCode version, but I will try to test that specifically to make sure. Is there a setting in VSCode to get this to work again?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Please see how to ask.
minimal reproducible example

Apologies if the question was unclear. What I would like is for matplotlib plots to appear directly after plt.plot(...), which is my understanding of how matplotlib is supposed to work in interactive mode (plt.ion()). It is working incorrectly in VSCode's Python extension -- when I execute the code or debug it in VSCode the plots do not show up when they are supposed to. I am wondering if there is either a VSCode/Python extension setting that I should change to get this to work properly, or a change to my matplotlib config to make matplotlib and VSCode+Python extension compatible.
